# Application of Itô's lemma - Forward process

Tags: interest-rates, pricing, stochastic

How would be applied the itô's lemma in the following equation:

[image]

And we know that:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is r_c? Why does it depend on T in your dS process?

Comment: r_c is the discrete spot interest rate compounded continuously, on date t, with expiration in T.  c denotes that is continuously

Comment: Discrete compounded continuously? I am a bit confused, but anyway lets take r to be the short rate, T is irrelevant in the dS. Since r is stochastic, that's how you specified it, then you cannot write P that way.

Comment: P is a zero cupon bond. So, P depends of r,t,T. Another way, to express r_c is: r_c=-(ln[P(t,T)]/(T-t))

Comment: What you are defining is the **yield** of the bond.

Comment: @ilovevolatility sorry, it's only compounded continuously. r_c is the spot interest rate compounded continuously. I read again, and sounds strange.

Comment: I think that I need apply a multivariate itô's formula, but I don't know how.

Comment: @JB1 I need to go offline and will give a longer answer tomorrow. But here are some short comments: 1. As Daneel Olivaw wrote your r_c looks like a yield to maturity, and the correct way to write is dS = r(t)Sdt + etc. 2. I am not sure if your question is why the forward process is driftless under the forward measure or how Ito works. So I recommend working first in a deterministic rate setting (e.g. r is constant) and calculate d(S/P). Since P is then deterministic, d(S/P) is no harder than normal Leibniz, but you still have the Ito part (dS)^2.

Comment: I appreciate your comments @ilovevolatility. My question is focused on how ito's lemma work in this specific case when r is stochastic, because as you said I prove do it assuming deterministic rate and I solved it. The solution behind the scenario of deterministic rate is that the variance of the forward process is equal to the variance of the spot process.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to find the dynamics of $F$? Hence $dF_t$

Comment: @Sanjay yees, because i need a formula of the variance of the forward process

Comment: Are you two Brownian Motions correlated?

Comment: yes, I added the correlation in the question section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by defining the function $f(t,s,r):=se^{r(T-t)}$ where $T$ is just a parameter here. The derivatives of $f$ is:
$$f_t(t,s,r)=-se^{r(T-t)} \text{ , } f_s(t,s,r)=e^{r(T-t)} \text{ , } f_r(t,s,r)=se^{r(T-t)}(T-t)\\
f_{s,s}(t,s,r)= 0 \text{ , }
f_{r,r}(t,s,r)=se^{r(T-t)}(T-t)^2 \text{ , } f_{s,r}(t,s,r) =  e^{r(T-t)}(T-t)
$$
Just to avoid conflict with mathematical formality redefine$F$ to be function of $t,S,r$ and $r(t)=r_c(t,T)$:
$$
dF(t,S(t),r(t))= \\ f_t(t,S(t),r(t)) dt + f_s(t,S(t),r(t)) dS(t)+ f_r(t,S(t),r(t)) dr(t)+\frac{1}{2}f_{r,r}(t,S(t),r(t)) (dr(t))^2+f_{r,s}(t,S(t),r(t)) dr(t)dS(t)
$$
Let's use the shorthand notation:

$$dF=  f_t dt + f_s dS+ f_r dr+\frac{1}{2}f_{r,r} (dr)^2+f_{r,s} drdS (1)$$
Note
$$drdS=\sigma_sS\sigma_rr\rho dt$$
$$(dr)^2=\sigma_r^2r^2dt$$

Now you have the relevant information to simplify equation 1 and after (a lot of) symbol-jiggling you should reach a decent expression for $dF$.

Please let me know if my (some how nonchalant) notation is confusing or not understable.

Comment: Then, the variance of the forward process is: (sigma_s)^2+(T-t)[(T-t)*((sigma_r)^2)+2*s*sigma_s*r*sigma_r*rho] It is correct? I'm not sure

Comment: @Sanjay if $r$ is stochastic, how can you write $P = e^{-r(T-t)}$ as you do in your derivation?

Comment: So guys,what would be the variance of the forward process? Because I not sure in what manners changes in comparison to be under normal assumption in terms of interest rate

Comment: I gave you the answer below. All you have to do is calculate $d(S/P)$ as explained in my answer. Which part is not clear?

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is the stochastic short rate then first of all you cannot write $P = e^{-r(t,T)(T-t)}$. The zero-coupon bond price will be 
$$
P(t,T) = E_t \left[ e^{- \int_t^T r_u du} \right]
$$
Now finding the dynamics of $P(t,T)$ given the dynamics of $r_t$ is, as far as I know, relatively easy only in so-called *affine term structure* models (ATS models). For your particular problem I think it's fine to start with supposing the dynamics of $P$ is given by
$$
dP = rP dt + \sigma_P P dW_r
$$
Note that the zero coupon $P$ dynamics is driven by the same $dW_r$ as the one that drives $r$ since $P$ depends on $r$. The risk-neutral drift of $P$ is $r$ as $P$ is a tradable asset. The $\sigma_P$ we will leave unspecified.

We can apply Ito now:
$$
d(S/P) = (1/P)dS + S d(1/P) + dS d(1/P)
$$
with
$$
d(1/P) = (-1/P^2) dP + (1/P^3) (dP)^2
$$
Now if you work this out you'll see what the drift is and the volatility is of $S/P$ under the risk-neutral measure $\mathcal{Q}$. To make the forward price driftless you do a measure change to work under the forward measure $\mathcal{Q}^T$. If $\sigma_P$ is zero due to constant or deterministic short rate then $(dP)^2 = 0$ and $dS d(1/P) = 0$, and the forward price is already driftless under $\mathcal{Q}$.